# How do I display the class attribute value python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like the gender value to be printed out when I print john.gender. How do I do this. What Do I need to edit in my code.

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self,name,gender,tribe):
        self.name = name
        self.gender ={
        0:"Male",
        1:"Female"
        }
        self.tribe ={
        0:"Germanic",
        1:"Egyptian",
        2:"Norse"
        }

   def saying(self):
       if self.tribe == 0:
          print(self.name, "I am from the great Germanic tribes")

john = Human("John",0,0)


print(john.gender)
```

Comment: 'print(john.gender)' did print out what the vaule is. Isn't it?

Comment: `self.gender` is dictionary with two entries. When instantiating `Human` as in the example `self.gender` is initialized with 0 and your mapping is gone.

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting John's gender in `__init__()`.  `Human().gender` will *always* be `{0: 'Male', 1: 'Female'}`.

If you want to lay it out like you have, you'll want something closer to the following:

```
def __init__(self, name, gender, tribe):
    ...
    genders = {
        0: 'Male',
        1: 'Female',
    }

    self.gender = genders[gender]

    ...
```

In the above example, we're setting `self.gender` to the *value* named by the key in the `genders` dict.

Comment: Use `get` method for safety. `self.gender = genders.get(gender, 'Unknown')`

Comment: @mypetlion: Not throwing KeyErrors isn't the same as safety; if you want to deal with weird gender options, there are better ways to do that than mapping everything but `0` and `1` to `'Unknown'`.

Comment: I'm fully aware that what I posted is not good code.  I was not aiming to write good code.  I was aiming to write something very simple and understandable, as the asker is having trouble with the very basics.  I really wish people here wouldn't always jump in with the most perfect complex solution when faced with a complete beginner.